# How do I transpose only single column keeping one column the same?

Tags: sql, sas

How do I transpose like this?
I know to Transpose it altogether but this one i am not familiar with.
[image]

Comment: Is there a column to provide the ordering you want in the pivoted result?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen we have only these two columns in hand and grouping could be done by **cust** column.

Comment: No, we need an _ordering_ in addition to a column for grouping.

Comment: Use a data step to add a counter and then use a PROC TRANSPOSE. Please post data as text not pictures, I'm not typing out your data. Also, show what you've attempted thus far. As stated this question doesn't meet SO rules.

Comment: Add counter: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/

Comment: Transpose https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Comment: Just add Cust to a `by` statement in `proc transpose`, instead of `id`.  No need for a counter

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
data a;
  cust = "A";
  channels = 20;
  output;
  cust = "A";
  channels = 30;
  output;
  cust = "A";
  channels = 40;
  output;
  cust = "B";
  channels = 200;
  output;
  cust = "B";
  channels = 300;
  output;
  cust = "B";
  channels = 0;
  output;
run;

proc transpose data=a out=b;
  by cust;
  var channels;
run;
```